# Хорошие книги по обучению c#

Tags: c#, книги

Привет всем.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, хорошую книгу по программированию программ на c#.
Я имею в виду не по изучению c#, а именно полное руководство по реализации полноценной программы, структура программы - последовательность проектирования.  Дело в том, что у меня есть идея проекта. Именно для этого я начал изучать си Шарп, конечно, мне и кроме проекта нравится это увлечение, можно сказать, хобби.

Совместно с изучением языка я все новое пытаюсь применить в своём проекте, так как бессмысленно изучать язык, не зная, как, что и где применять. Я про интерфейсы, делегаты и события сто раз читал. Так и не понял, где и как применять. И все время прихожу к тому, что просто делаю ссылки на классы и через переменную вызываю методы. Конечно, таким способом я давно бы уже закончил свой проект, без всяких заморочек. Но все-таки хотелось бы подойти более профессиональней к этому вопросу. Я раз пять уже переписывал свой проект и прихожу все к одному - к полному беспорядку, сто форм, 1000 классов и полный Хаус.

P.S. Книгу желательно на русском языке, так как мой английский не на том уровне, чтоб понимать то, что и на русском не всегда понимаю.

Comment: Этому больше учат не книги по C#, а книги по проектированию программного обеспечения. Всякие методологии(восходящее и нисходящее проектирование, модульные системы, case, uml), паттерны и антипаттерны, структуры данных. Гради Буч - объектно-ориентированное проектирование, книга четырех, кормен - алгоритмы, гамма - Приемы объектно-ориентированного проектирования,  и т.д. и т.п. Правда хорошую обзорную книгу я подсказать не могу, не встречал.

--------

Ну и конечно полезно смотреть в чужой код, как большие системы делают люди с опытом.

Comment: Ну и вдогонку: [Классические книги по C#](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.co.il/2011/04/cnet.html), но, скорее всего, они не покроют многие вопросы.

Comment: @Alex Krass список конечно замечательный, но до большинства из этих книг ТСу еще расти и расти, да и от конкретных технологий они абстрагированы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как язык один, но приложения на нем могут создаваться самые разные - и десктопные, и веб-приложения, и службы, даже под андроиды-маки, да и вообще много всякого разного, то вполне логично, что под каждую соответствующую платформу есть свои конкретные руководства по разработке приложений. Поэтому я также порекомендую книгу по конкретной платформе.

Под ваши критерии подойдет очень неплохая книга Адама Фримена "**[Pro ASP.NET MVC](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/19611803/)**". Она есть в русском переводе и регулярно переиздается при выходе новых версий ASP.NET MVC (правда русский перевод запаздывает на 1-2 версии). И организована она таким образом, что за основу взято поэтапное написание веб-приложения с рассмотрением большинства важных аспектов разработки приложения - паттерн MVC, юнит-тестирование, инверсия зависимостей и много других интересных и нужных вещей. Помимо этого в книге обзорно рассматриваются некоторые полезные аспекты самого языка (типа Linq) и, разумеется, описаны многие аспекты именно веб-разработки. Несмотря на то, что книга привязана именно к веб-программированию, большинство описываемых в ней методик хорошо подойдет для разработки любых типов приложений 9в частности, те же юнит-тесты используются повсеместно независимо от типов приложений)

Comment: Да, извините, забыл указать: я пишу программу для windows  с формами в общем.

Comment: про WinForms не скажу, но вообще технология эта довольно паршивая и не особо перспективная, однако в указанной мной книге многие методики применимы не только к веб-приложениям, но и к любым другим

Comment: вот не плохое пособие, для моего вопроса.
Если новичкам будет интересно.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6RNy3rPZpg

хоть проект из урока я сделал, но, ведать, я еще слаб в программировании, чтобы осознать и действительно понять, что там происходит, вернее, я понимаю, но как это применить в моей задаче, то увы :(.
значит буду продолжать свой проект таким способом, как и делал изначально

Answer (score 1):

Для начала предлагаю почитать книгу Эндрю Троелсена Язык программирования C# 5.0 и платформа. NET 4.5.   Там есть и про язык и про библиотеки и про структуру проекта. Очень дружелюбное изложение.

Для для более глубокого изучения именно самого языка C# рекомендую "C# 5.0 Справочник Полное описание языка" Джозеф Албахари и Бен Албахари. Авторы очень глубоко разбираются в нюансах языка и дают много полезных примеров.

Для программы с Формами, то есть десктопного приложения рекомендуемая технология WPF. По ней есть хорошая книга Windows Presentation Foundation в NET 4.5 с примерами на C# 5.0 для профессионалов Мэтью Мак-Дональд.

Технология Windows Forms считается устаревшей. Ее подробное описание можно найти в более старых изданиях книг по платформе .Net. В новых книгах она излагается кратко в приложении.

На эту тему есть подробная информация здесь [Книги по C# и другая литература](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-c-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0)